# Why did the Ubuntu installer stopped after the Ubuntu logo screen? It didn't run afterwards

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I tried installing Ubuntu by replacing my Windows. While doing so, I erased my SSD which had Windows installed in it, and then tried installing Ubuntu. I used Rufus to make my USB bootable. Everything was going fine but then the installer just halted on the Ubuntu logo screen while the installation starts. The loading animation stopped. I waited a long, nothing happened. Now I'm left with no OS. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Subedi,

Before trying something else. Run it again, otherwise maybe you have a bad copy of the image on the USB.
Have you checked that the copy of your files on your linux bootable USB has all the files? You can find the md5sum of the image and compart it with the md5 list present in the iso.

Sometimes you can get a bad copy of one of the files so checking that would be a good starting point.